# javascript code to change clip rect settings

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the window is resized, the blurred image is resized as well. For some reason the code is not working. Can someone spot what is wrong and what I need to do to correct the code. Thanks.

- CSS -

/* ------- BLUR BEHIND MESSAGE HOLDER CONTAINER SETTINGS ------- */

```
img.clipphoto { 
    /*--- CLIP SETTINGS: top, right, bottom, left ---*/
    clip: rect(18px,770px,600px,240px);

    position: absolute;
        -webkit-filter: blur(10px); 
        -moz-filter: blur(10px); 
        -o-filter: blur(10px); 
        -ms-filter: blur(10px); 
        filter: blur(10px);

    }
```

- JS -

  ```
  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  var vInnerHeight= window.innerHeight; 

  var t = "18";
  var r = "770";
  var b = vInnerHeight-140;
  var l = "240";

  var clipString = "rect(" + t + "px " + r + "px " + b + "px " + l + "px)";

  document.getElementByClassName(clipphoto).style.clip = clipString;
  ```
- HTML -

  ```
  <!-- blurred photo of pix  -->
      <img src="images/image1.png" width="1200" height="620" alt="" class="clipphoto">
  ```

Comment: Your original `clip:` in the CSS has commas.  Those aren't in your `clipString`. You might also want to make a jsfiddle so people don't need to reconstruct your scenario in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementByClassName()` function. It's `getElementsByClassName()` (plural).

And you want the string "clipphoto", not the (non-existant) variable named `clipphoto`:

```
var clipString = "rect(" + t + "px, " + r + "px, " + b + "px, " + l + "px)";
document.getElementsByClassName('clipphoto')[0].style.clip = clipString;
```

Comment: Thanks. Ir works great. It's usually something so simple. And yes I will make a jsfiddle in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Believe the values should be comma separated, not space separated

```
var clipString = "rect(" + t + "px," + r + "px," + b + "px," + l + "px)";

document.getElementsByClassName('clipphoto')[0].style.clip = clipString;
```

Edit: incorporated class accessor errror by Paul Roub too